# OrderBy selector fails while projecting anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

When using Entity Framework 5, why would this work?

```
var query = Categories.Select(c => new 
    { 
        Products = c.Products.OrderBy(p => p.Name) 
    });
```

While this won't?

```
Func<Product, string> selector = p => p.Name;
var query = Categories.Select(c => new 
    { 
        Products = c.Products.OrderBy(selector) 
    });
```

The thrown exception is: Unsupported overload used for query operator 'OrderBy'.

Comment: Tell me.. does `Products = c.Products.ToList().OrderBy(selector)` work?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: No, it doesn't work, same exception. Anyway, even if calling ToList() works, it wouldn't be a nice solution when the products are being filtered before ordering, because ordering will happen in memory.

Comment: This worked fine for me.  Can you provide a working sample that throws this exception?

Comment: @DanCsharpster: The second block above is a working sample. You just need to create a database with 2 tables, Category(Id, Name) and Product(Id, Name, CategoryId) with one-to-many relationship, and put the code in LINQPad.

Comment: That is not exactly a "working sample".  By working sample, I mean something I can throw into VS or linqpad and just run it.  I and the rest of the community are happy to help, but you are much more likely to get the answer you're looking for if you don't require us to jump through hoops to help you.  Give us a sample that exactly reproduces the problem so we can hit the ground running, to help you.  I have a sample showing the query itself working.  I'll post that as an answer below.  I think Honza is onto something though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `selector` an `Expression<Func<Product, string>>` won't work directly and will not compile because `c.Products` is not an `IQueryable<T>`. It is just a collection type implementing only `IEnumerable<T>`. `Enumerable.OrderBy` does not accept an expression as parameter, only a delegate.

But EF still needs an expression, not a delegate. The trick is to use `AsQueryable()` on the navigation collection:

```
Expression<Func<Product, string>> selector = p => p.Name;
var query = Categories.Select(c => new 
{ 
    Products = c.Products.AsQueryable().OrderBy(selector) 
});
```

Comment: @user2604373: What database are you using?

Comment: @user2604373: And `Categories` in your question is of type `DbSet<Category>`, right?

Comment: Using LINQPad, it's EntitySet<Category>.

Comment: @user2604373: `EntitySet` is LINQ to SQL and not Entity Framework. There are more details in your question needed. Right now you are driving users into the wrong direction with the lack of details and correct infos.

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. The AsQueryable() solves it in EF, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The `query` variable name hints that you may be using Entity Framework, LINQ to SQL or some other `IQueryable<T>` based API. You are passing the `selector` as `Func`. The underlying query provider cannot translate `Func` to SQL (or any other language, whatever you may be using).

Change the type of `selector` to `Expression<Func<Product, string>>` (the rest can remain the same, because lambda expressions can be interpreted either as a delegate or an expression tree. That's why you can's use `var` with lambdas - the compiler just can't tell if you want the lambda to be a delegate or expression tree) and see if that fixes your problem. You haven't provided enough information for me to be 100% sure, but it should. The `OrderBy` overloads accepting an `Expression` should be able to walk the expression tree and translate it to the underlying query. It's somewhat a guess, but I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you. I tried the Expression<Func<Product, string>> before posting this question. It doesn't work as well.

Comment: @user2604373 That means that the particular expression you provided couldn't be parsed by the query provider.  Without knowing what the actual expression is there really isn't any more for us to say.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of the query working okay and not causing a problem.  I skipped the database for simplicity and went directly to an in-memory object, which is probably why it's working for me.  I think Honza is right, that this is an issue related to the ORM layer.  You can run the below example

Here is an example for linqpad:

```
void Main()
{

        var Categories = new List<Category>() { new Category { CategoryName = "CatName", Products = new List<Product>() { new Product { Name = "ProductName1" } } } };

        Func<Product, string> selector = p => p.Name;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var query = Categories.Select(c => new
        {
            Products = c.Products.OrderBy(selector)
        });
        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(x.Products.First().Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        Console.Read();


    }


    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
```

// Define other methods and classes here

Here is a version for visual studio console app:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var Categories = new List<Category>() { new Category { CategoryName = "CatName", Products = new List<Product>() { new Product { Name = "ProductName1" } } } };
        Func<Product, string> selector = p => p.Name;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var query = Categories.Select(c => new
        {
            Products = c.Products.OrderBy(selector)
        });
        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(x.Products.First().Name);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        Console.Read();


    }


    public class Product
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Category
    {
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it works this way, but when you do it using entity framework, it throws the exception. I will edit my question and mention that I am using entity framework. Thank you Dan.